# Removing Elements from a KML (Python)

Tags: python, xml, automation, gis, kml

I generated a KML file using Python's SimpleKML library and the following script, the output of which is also shown below:

```
import simplekml
kml = simplekml.Kml()
ground = kml.newgroundoverlay(name='Aerial Extent')
ground.icon.href = 'C:\\Users\\mdl518\\Desktop\\aerial_image.png'
ground.latlonbox.north = 46.55537
ground.latlonbox.south = 46.53134
ground.latlonbox.east = 48.60005
ground.latlonbox.west = 48.57678
ground.latlonbox.rotation = 0.090320 
kml.save(".//aerial_extent.kml")
```

The output KML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
    <Document id="1">
        <GroundOverlay id="2">
            <name>Aerial Extent</name>
            <Icon id="3">
                <href>C:\\Users\\mdl518\\Desktop\\aerial_image.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <LatLonBox>
                <north>46.55537</north>
                <south>46.53134</south>
                <east>48.60005</east>
                <west>48.57678</west>
                <rotation>0.090320</rotation>
        </LatLonBox>
    </GroundOverlay>
</Document>
```

However, I am trying to remove the "Document" tag from this KML since it is a default element generated with SimpleKML, while keeping the child elements (e.g. GroundOverlay).  Additionally, is there a way to remove the "id" attributes associated with specific elements (i.e. for the GroundOverlay, Icon elements)?  I am exploring the usage of ElementTree/lxml to enable this, but these seem to be more specific to XML files as opposed to KMLs.  Here's what I'm trying to use to modify the KML, but it is unable to remove the Document element:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.fromstring(open("C:\\Users\\mdl518\\Desktop\\aerial_extent.kml").read())
for item in tree.xpath("//Document[@id='1']"):
    item.getparent().remove(item)

print(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True))
```

Here is the final desired output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
    <GroundOverlay>
         <name>Aerial Extent</name>
         <Icon>
             <href>C:\\Users\\mdl518\\Desktop\\aerial_image.png</href>
         </Icon>
         <LatLonBox>
              <north>46.55537</north>
              <south>46.53134</south>
              <east>48.60005</east>
              <west>48.57678</west>
              <rotation>0.090320</rotation>
         </LatLonBox>
    </GroundOverlay>
</kml>
```

Any insights are most appreciated!

Comment: KML files are also XML, so lxml is a fine way to manipulate them. Whether it'll still be valid KML after your modifications, that's up to you of course :)

Comment: @Thomas - I get that KMLs are essentially XMLs, but I was just observing what seemed to be sensitivities to the file extensions using the lxml/ElementTree libraries.  I updated my post showing the script I am attempting to use to remove the Document tag, any assistance is most appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting tripped up on the dreaded namespaces...

Try using something like this:

```
ns = {'kml': 'http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'}
for item in tree.xpath("//kml:Document[@id='1']",namespaces=ns):
    item.getparent().remove(item)
```

Edit:

To remove just the parent and retain all its descendants, try the following:

```
retain = doc.xpath("//kml:Document[@id='1']/kml:GroundOverlay",namespaces=ns)[0]
for item in doc.xpath("//kml:Document[@id='1']",namespaces=ns):
    anchor = item.getparent()
    anchor.remove(item)
    anchor.insert(1,retain)

print(etree.tostring(doc, pretty_print=True).decode())
```

This should get you the desired output.

Comment: This is helpful in pointing me in the right direction, but executing this script removes all child elements below the "Document" element.  I will keep plugging away at this as there should only be a few more tweaks to get the correct solution, thanks again!

Comment: @mdl518 Well, that's what you said in your question - you wanted to remove the `<Document>` element; that includes everything inside it. If that's not what you are after, you probably should post another question with different xml and desired output.

Comment: My apologies for any ambiguity, but yes the idea is to remove the Document element while keeping the child elements (e.g. GroundOverlay).  This is now reflected in the updated post.

Comment: @mdl518 I understand now, but you should probably edit your question again and show the **exact** expected output.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful feedback, this is now added to the original post...most appreciated!

Comment: I included this edit, but now receive an "IndexError: list index out of range". Here is the merged script which is giving the error (beginning at retain=root.xpath..)

`import lxml.etree as ET
tree = ET.parse('C:\\Users\\mdl518\\Desktop\\aerial_extent.kml')
root = tree.getroot()  
retain = root.xpath("//kml:Document[@id='1']/kml:GroundOverlay",namespaces=ns)[0]
for item in root.xpath("//kml:Document[@id='1']",namespaces=ns):
    anchor = item.getparent()
    anchor.remove(item)
    anchor.insert(1,retain)
print(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True).decode())`

Comment: @mdl518 Don't know what to tell you; it works for me and it works here: https://onlinegdb.com/rkWqrtieu

Comment: Thank you for providing the embedded link...the script works seamlessly!  I was apparently missing the line "doc = etree.XML(kml.encode())" from your original edit.  Is there a slick way to remove the "id" attributes associated with the GroundOverlay and Icon elements?  I will otherwise go ahead and confirm your solution as the correct answer, thanks again!

Comment: @mdl518 As to removing the `id` attribute: probably, but I have to think about it and, in any event, as per SO policy, you should probably post it as a separate question. Otherwise, I'm glad it worked for you!

Comment: Yes, the script works great!  Regarding the "id" attributes, I had posted this as a secondary question about this workflow in my original post.  I can dig into this a bit more, but any further assistance is most appreciated!  :)